# Best possible way to remove html elements that are in an js array?

Tags: javascript, html

What i need is a JS function deleteSelected()
That removes the elements that are in the selectedDivs array from my HTML page. What is the most effective way?

Delete selected
HTML:

```
<div class="DRAGGABLE ui-draggable" onclick="addDevice(this)" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; height: 41px; top: 126px; left: 27px;">
  <img id="PMF00" src="/devices/AIRC1-010.gif">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function addDevice(e) {
  if ($ctrlBeingpressed == true) {
    selectedDivs.push(e);
    e.style.border = "2px dotted black";
  }
}
```

Apparantely there is already a post for this :/

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asked us how to remove nodes from the DOM, or DOM elements that you've added to a simple JS array? Because most of the answers are for the first one.

Comment: Not remove from the array, but remove from the page.

Answer (score 5):

If your `selectedDivs` array contains actual DOM elements, you can do the following:

```
function deleteSelected() {
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedDivs.length; i++) {
      var el = selectedDivs[i];
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
   }
   selectedDivs = [];
}
```

Comment: Will onclick="addDevice(this)" provide the DOM element ?

Comment: Very strange, this works only the first time, after that it gives; TypeError: el.parentNode is null

Comment: @Firebirdz it is because elements are still in array, but not in DOM. You need to clear your `selectedDivs` once the method finished. Edited answer.

Comment: You are my hero Artyom Neustroev!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `removeChild` method

```
for (var i = 0, len = selectedDivs.length; i< len; i++){
  var node = selectedDivs[i];
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```